# How to assign variable names to individual rows in a csv file and access the same in python?

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning

I have a certain data in my csv file, which i use as a training data to train my classifier. In the python code, i define the entire data as a set of rows in x_train variable and the labels in y_train. this is fixed. Can i change the code in such a way that, by assigning a variable name to each individual row, like variable 'a' for row[0], if the data is changed in the training set, the code should automatically update with the new data and give the output.

The code is :

```
import sklearn
import numpy as np


#Importing a local data set from the desktop
import pandas as pd
mydata = pd.read_csv('apple.csv',skipinitialspace=True)
#print mydata

x_train = [[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,0]]
y_train = ['html','html','python','python','cpp']
x_test = ([[1,1,0]])

from sklearn import tree
classi = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
classi.fit(x_train, y_train)

predictions = classi.predict(x_test)
print predictions
```

The training data is :

```
 x1,x2,x3,y
a 0,0,0,html
b 0,1,0,html
c 0,1,1,python
d 1,1,1,python
e 1,1,0,cpp
```

Can anyone please help me with this ??

Update : 
When the below code is executed,

```
x_train = [[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,0]]
y_train = ['html','html','python','python','cpp']
x_test = ([[1,1,0]])
```

i get the output as,

```
['cpp']
```

What i want is :

```
x_train = [['a'],['b'],['c'],['d'],['e']]
y_train = ['html','html','python','python','cpp']
x_test = ([[1,1,0]])
```

And the output should remain the same again !
how to do that! If i try the above code, i am getting a lot of errors !!

Comment: I have re-read your question a few times and I am still unsure what you mean. Can you write an example output/update that you want..

Comment: The above program is working , till the data in the variable, x_train remains unaltered.the above program is a small part of me trying to count certain string in a document , put that counted number as a csv data, and then use that data to train my classifier. So, i am thinking like, instead of changing the data in the above variable, every single time, why not assign a variable name to each row, just like i have given names like x1,x2,x3 and y, and use those names to point the row, whose data might change accordingly , which would make my work easy.

Comment: So you want to label individual rows with a unique identifier?

Comment: ya. but i am getting a lot of errors if i try the code as u can see in the updated post !

Comment: basically what you are doing is creating a classifier that predicts on the domain `['a','b','c','d','e']` and then you give the classifier something that is `[1,1,0]` which has three features. so essentially you have a tree that splits on one feature rather than 3 which is what you are trying to pass in to predict on. If you want the result you would pass in `e` into your predict function. But it seems silly to have a classifier on a unique row id.

Comment: i tried passing in 'e' into my predict function, which gave me an error,       [" could not convert string to float: e  "]